# How to derive the general element of a sequence from its generating function?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For example, from the sequence $f_n=2f_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}f_{n-2}$ and starting elements $f_0=f_1=1$ I derived the generating function $F=\frac{1-x-x^2}{1-2x-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$

How would I reverse the process and derive $f_n$ given just the generating function?

Edit: My $F$ is wrong. Right value should be $F=\frac{1-x}{1-2x-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$

Comment: Is that $F$ right?

Comment: I think so. I can update my question with how I found it, if you wish

Comment: Can you see any similarity between the denominator and the recursive relationship?

Comment: @MathLover Wow, it's very obvious actually. Can't believe I missed that. How does the numerator figure in though? And is there a way to get $f_n$ from $F$ in a formula not dependant on $f_{n-1}$ and $f_{n-2}$

Comment: Factor the denominator into linear factors, then expand using partial fractions, then recognize the terms as generating functions e.g. $\frac{\alpha}{1 - \beta x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha \beta^n x^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$F$ is wrong. Anyway  suppose that the right was $F(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{\frac{x^2}{2}+2 x-1}$

You have to expand it in MacLaurin series:
$$F(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } f_n x^n$$
$f_n$ will be the solution

Hope this helps